# Unable to run "monodevelop.azurefunctions.8.8" with HomeBrew on MacBook Pro

Tags: azure-functions, homebrew, monodevelop, visual-studio-mac

I am new to using HomeBrew and I was trying to install an extension for a source code repository from a book to use in Visual Studio for Mac.

The command:

```
brew install monodevelop.azurefunctions.8.8
```

This is what happened:

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Homebrew has enabled anonymous aggregate formula and cask analytics.
Read the analytics documentation (and how to opt-out) here:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Analytics
No analytics have been recorded yet (nor will be during this `brew` run).

==> Homebrew is run entirely by unpaid volunteers. Please consider donating:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew#donations
==> Tapping homebrew/core
Cloning into '/Users/xxxxx/git/brew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 36, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (36/36), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly6.11 MiB | 718.00 KiB/s
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Error: Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core /Users/xxxxx/git/brew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core` exited with 128.
Error: Failure while executing; `/Users/xxxxx/git/brew/bin/brew tap homebrew/core` exited with 1.
==> Tapping homebrew/core
Cloning into '/Users/xxxxx/git/brew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 36, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (36/36), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly51.01 MiB | 5.71 MiB/s
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Error: Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core /Users/xxxxx/git/brew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core` exited with 128.
Error: Failure while executing; `/Users/xxxxx/git/brew/bin/brew tap homebrew/core` exited with 1.
```

I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular instance I was trying to use this [source code](https://github.com/macNetCore/CodeBook/tree/master/Chapter5/configProgram).

I found that if I installed the .NET Core 3.0 from the official website that the warning about needing this extension went away.